# NGINX rewrite for static dir

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to translate:

mydomain.com/98387634/image/file.png

to:

mydomain.com/image/file.png

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my rewrite?

```
rewrite ^~/static/(.*)/(.*)$ ~/static/$2 last;

location ^~/static {
        expires max;
        root /var/www;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `*' AND`+' in regular expressions are greedy.
You must use `.*?' or write rewrite something like this:

```
rewrite ^~/static/[^/]*/(.*)$ ~/static/$1 last;
```